# Where are located custom themes?

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I am making a new theme and have clicked on the + button in the Theme tab in User Preferences and named it but when i go in "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\presets\interface_theme" i don't see my custom theme.

Where is my custom theme located in Windows?

Comment: Thank you! Add your message as answer so i can toggle the solved button. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows's Blender preferences, scripts, and themes are located at:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version number: ex. 2.78>\
```

The theme folder is located at:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version number: ex. 2.78>\scripts\presets\interface_theme
```

For example,

```
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\presets\interface_theme
```

Answer (score 0):

The customs presets are under presets tab. click on the presets and a drop down will appear click on the any preset them. Select any them and never forget to save user settings below.
[image]